# How to submit Laravel VueJS dynamic form data?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to Vue.js. I am trying to make a form dynamic (only a certain part of the form dynamic.). A user can have multiple guarantors. So I made the Guarantor form Dynamic with VueJS. When I submit the form and return the request, I see only the last array. Its always the last array, all others are lost.

This is the blade file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css')}}">

    <title>Laravel</title>


</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">

        <div class="container pt-5">

            <form action="{{ route('submit.store')}}" method="post">
                @csrf

                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">User Detail</h4>


                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-1" name="user_name" id="user_name" placeholder="Name" />

                    <input type="email" class="form-control mb-1" name="user_email" id="user_email"
                        placeholder="Email" />

                    <textarea name="about" class="form-control" id="about" cols="30" rows="10"
                        placeholder="About"></textarea>

                </div>

                <dynamic-form></dynamic-form>



            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is how the VueComponent looks.

```html
<template>
  <div>
      <button class="btn btn-success mb-3" @click.prevent="addNewUser">Add User</button>

      <div class="card mb-3" v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index">

          <div class="card-body">
              <span class="float-right" style="cursor:pointer" @click.prevent="removeForm(index)" >X</span>
              <h4 class="card-title">Guarantor No: {{ index }}</h4>


                <input type="text" class="form-control mb-1" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" v-model="user.name" />

                <input type="email" class="form-control mb-1" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" v-model="user.email"/>

                <textarea name="about" class="form-control" id="about" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="About" v-model="user.about"></textarea>

          </div>

      </div>

      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">



  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

    name: 'dynamic-form',

    data() {
        return{
            users: [
                {
                    name: '',
                    email: '',
                    about: ''

                }
            ]

        }
    },

    methods: {
          addNewUser: function() {
              this.users.push({
                  name: '',
                  email: '',
                  about: ''

              });
          },
          removeForm: function(index) {
              this.users.splice(index, 1);
          }
    }

}
</script>
```

How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: Why do you not use the full form in the Vue component?

Comment: Hi, There some more dynamic data from the database that are used to construct the form. For simplicity, I have passed the data from the controller, such as client level which is not included here.

Comment: you can pass controller data using vue props.  also, you can retrieve data from ajax request. I think it is a easiest way to manage data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, values with the same `name` attribute value will get overwritten. (See the "How do I get all the results from a select multiple HTML tag?" section [here](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays)).

You can create arrays of values by adding a bracket to the name. For example, if you made the `name` of the "name" input `name[]`, `name` will be an array of names in PHP.

In your case, you could use this format: `name="guarantors[][name]"`. That way you will get an array in PHP under the key `guarantors` (e.g. `$request->guarantors`) and each of the values in `guarantors` will be an array with the values `name`, `email`, etc.